# Complemento indirecto en "Guillermo participó en la carrera de ayer."

Tags: gramática

En la oración "Guillermo participó en la carrera de ayer", ¿"en la carrera"  es un complemento indirecto o es un complemento circunstancial de lugar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Participar* (en esa [acepción](https://www.rae.es/dpd/participar)) es verbo intransitivo, luego [no puede llevar](https://www.unprofesor.com/lengua-espanola/verbos-transitivos-e-intransitivos-ejemplos-1680.html) objeto directo ni indirecto.

Answer (score 3):

"En la carrera de ayer" es un **complemento de régimen (preposicional)**. La construcción *participar en* es uno de los ejemplos en el capítulo 36 (*El complemento de régimen preposicional*) de la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española (NGLE)*. Concretamente aparece en la sección [§36.4b](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pGDbZyxKaIkLILWj).

Un **complemento de régimen** es un sintagma preposicional cuya preposición viene regida (requerida) por el verbo. Existen muchos verbos que rigen determinadas preposiciones, como *pensar en*, *soñar con*, *invitar a*... El complemento que contiene la preposición regida es el complemento de régimen:

- Guillermo participó **en la carrera de ayer**
- Estoy pensando **en las dificultades que se avecinan**

Nótese que el complemento es "en la carrera de ayer", porque "de ayer" modifica a "la carrera", y no al verbo "participó".